# Outlook internet free-busy on Dropbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dropbox

How would I be able to share my Outlook "internet free-busy" status via Dropbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Outlook 2010 the following works

First go to File->Options->Calendar

Click on "Free-Busy" options

[image]

Click on "Other Free/busy"

[image]

Set the location to somewhere in your "Public" part of your dropbox. Such as

> file://\localhost\c$\Users\user\Dropbox\Public\outlook\name.vfb

Search location should be something like the following and point to the folder where you share your items together with others.

> file://\localhost\c$\Users\user\Dropbox\Public\outlook\%NAME%.vfb

[image]

To allow others to retrieve your free busy information you will need to share it in your contact. There is a field in the contact details to do this.

[image]

This seems to work, but not always, it depends on settings on the client sometimes proxies and firewall does not allow dropbox in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've not actually used this, but from the [manual](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291621) i would guess you use the file:// format to save it somewhere in your public folder, and get the other person to use the dropbox link from the public folder to view/add it

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to not use a UNC for a local path because the C$ is an administrative share and thus may not be accessible to the end user.

A better way to use the file:// path is to use it like this:

file://C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Public\outlook\%NAME%.vfb